# How to map a function over all properties of an object while keeping type safety?

Tags: typescript

I have these two TypeScript definitions:

```js
interface Snapshot {
    guild: Guild;
    channels: ChannelsDataModel;
    roles: RolesDataModel;
    emojis: EmojisDataModel;
    stickers: StickersDataModel;
    permissionOverwrites: PermissionOverwritesDataModel;
    bans: BansDataModel;
    metadata: SnapshotMetadata;
}

type SerializedSnapshot = { [Property in keyof Snapshot]: string };
```

Basically what that means is that, when serializing `Snapshot`, all properties get converted to a string using `JSON.stringify()` over that property and `SerializedSnapshot` describes just that.

However, when creating the new serialized object, I would have to write this repetitive piece of code:

```js
function serializeSnapshot(snapshot: Snapshot): SerializedSnapshot {
    // I already removed a bit of code repetition by creating this inner function, but that's not much.
    function stringify(value: any): string {
        return JSON.stringify(value, null, 2);
    }

    return {
        guild: stringify(snapshot.guild),
        channels: stringify(snapshot.channels),
        roles: stringify(snapshot.roles),
        emojis: stringify(snapshot.emojis),
        stickers: stringify(snapshot.stickers),
        permissionOverwrites: stringify(snapshot.permissionOverwrites),
        bans: stringify(snapshot.bans),
        metadata: stringify(snapshot.metadata),
    };
}
```

What bothers me is that the object creation forces me to repeat `stringify()` for each property of the original object. Being a fan of the `map()` function, I wish there would be a way to "map" one property of an object to another object that (clearly from the example) **has the same property names (or keys?)** but they differ in type. Their type would be the return type of the hypothetical property mapping function. Essentially, *a way to make TypeScript understand that the resulting object has the same property names with a different value, defined by the map function*.

Is something like this doable in TypeScript's type system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is something like this doable in TypeScript's type system?

There are two answers to that:

- Yes, it's what's in your question as `SerializedSnapshot`.
- No, because you're talking about a **runtime** process of changing values from non-strings to strings.

So the type part of — the TypeScript type system part — you're already doing. But the *runtime* part still needs doing.

You can do it by using [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get an array of `[key, value]` tuples for the object, `map` to convert the values in those to strings, and [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to build the new object if you don't mind the intermediate arrays:

```
return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(snapshot).map(([key, value]) => [key, stringify(value)])
) as SerializedSnapshot;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMojgBwM4AsD2YyA3gFDIXIDmArsADYAmAXMgOJ1MDc5lCucECAj1srAMIChI7ABE4YOAFl8jET0rIo+ehDHIASjr3zFKtfQ2UIAW3wArYPoCidx3IXLV63hWxhgBABraH1UAODQ0y8LKwpMaBsnbGB8EAB5ADdoAHcoYEh9AAVE5NSM7Kg8gpNPcx9NACNBfQAhFuj6y19kGwhFRk9WdCw8QiV+uEHFHgBfUlIwAE8EtGhgOHpgAC8IRhGcAiIAXhJkAG0i7QSoZeRQZBCl-Bg0DEPCAF1Wf3yQKmQsx4pBgNBACACaWQ2HWmx2EAOYzAAApsO8kcN0UcAJTDWFbXb7LGEEg9AD0ZOQAElkJsoBApkstLZ8NlGLTkI0CsgXsgEN5mQkApCQJymQh6QpQACwLgnPdpFBkKDwSKADScmhEWUKADk2GQIBJNho-AAdD0VRDytCwH8qMAYEtkZlNjQIKxBEtcbb7aTNJp6WAaFBRQApVDpAByZt+0sdztd9HdGpANHo9A1ACZsXFAQtA-0Q6L0o17BAIWaYNobM5wPk9MieppS+XKxB68BG2jRjizTYsMjkecnhqk+7PtjkMcAHwXUe++NOl1uiDYyc9KdwA2ofHwom9whzIA)

I can't say I like the type assertion it requires, but in very well-controlled, limited situations like your `serializeSnapshot`, a type assertion may be okay.